# Pattern matching is not giving the expected results

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Pattern matching is not working as per the understanding.

I read the pattern matching concepts in the text book "Programming in Scala".

I have a pattern matching definition as below.

```
def checkMe (a:Any) =  a match {
      case Int => "I am an Integer"
      case Double => "I am a Double"
      case Char => "I am a Charecter"
      case _ => "I am something else"
     }
```

Irregardless whatever I pass while calling to the function, always the default case is executed.

E.g: checkMa(100) gives "I am something else"
     checkMe(10.) too gives "I am something else" etc..

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong in the definition.

I expect the definition executing according to the type I pass.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that you are matching against the companion object (Int, Double, Char) instead of the actual type, a solution is to match against the type like this:

```
def checkMe (a:Any) =  a match {
  case _: Int => "I am an Integer"
  case _: Double => "I am a Double"
  case _: Char => "I am a Charecter"
  case _ => "I am something else"
}
```

Then, you can test in a REPL to see the expected results:

```
@ checkMe(4) 
res3: String = "I am an Integer"

@ checkMe(4.0) 
res4: String = "I am a Double"

@ checkMe('a') 
res5: String = "I am a Charecter"

@ checkMe("Asdas") 
res6: String = "I am something else"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have hard time to understand the difference. Even When I compare with companion object, the return type of it is Integer, Double etc. So it needs to be give the expected result even when I use companion object.

Comment: You can try to see the companion object as the singleton representation of the class, for example, a `Boolean` would have 3 possible instances, `true`, `false`, and the companion object, in the code from your question, you are actually checking whether the instances are the companion object.

Comment: Thanks Alex!  When I read few examples, case classes are compared like the companion objects which I put in my question. How is the case class (with out type mentioned)  gives correct results?

Answer (score 4):

you need a `variable: Type` to pattern match,

```
  def checkMe(a: Any) = a match {
    case a: Int => "I am an Integer"
    case a: Double => "I am a Double"
    case a: Char => "I am a Charecter"
    case _ => "I am something else"
  }
```

example - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/Pxzn4w8GQGCMIub33xMrRg/1